# Setting the rootViewController after a modal view has been presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an app where I re-init the app if it's been in the background for too long. When the user opens up the app after the allotted time, the re-init happens, and I display the splash screen while I get the data I need. When I get the data from the server I set the `window.rootViewController` property to a new value. If the old root view controller has had a view controller presented modally, and that view controller was being displayed when the re-init happens, dealloc doesn't get called on the view controller (I've tested this by putting NSLog's in the dealloc method). In the case where a modal view controller was not presented, the dealloc gets called as expected.

Does anyone know of a solution to this? I'm not sure if it's an Apple bug, or if it's something that I need to handle on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that I came up with was before I set the RootViewController, I call

```
- (void)_dismissRootViewControllersModalViewsIfAny {
    UIViewController *rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
    if (rootViewController.presentedViewController || rootViewController.presentingViewController) 
    {
        [rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

This is a method that I created, which makes sure that if there is a modal view controller to dismiss, it will be dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Your modal view is presented by the rootViewController (it's `presentingViewController` property is set to the rootViewController), that might be the source of your problem.

You can set your rootViewController to an instance of UINavigationController and then just use its `setViewControllers:animated:` method to display a freshly instantiated view controller instead of switching the window's rootViewController.